# Trouble loading wildcard SSL that uses the hostname

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have a wildcard SSL cert from Let's Encrypt, the installation has worked and when accessing a sub-domain the cert loads properly. However the virtual site (Apache) that has *no subdomain* produces an error:

```
[Wed Jun 28 15:21:18.823772 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 3713433:tid 140282501949760] AH01909: abc.net:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

Note this variation of the domain is also the hostname of the server, I don't know if that is causing a problem? In the browser no cert seems to load, at least there is no mention of Let's Encrypt or any other expected details.

The cert was created with the following command:

```
certbot certonly --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --manual --preferred-challenges dns -d 'abc.net, *.abc.net'
```

When viewing the cert on the sub-domain indeed both domains with and without a subdomain are showing in the details, so it has been registered properly.

The virual site entries for both sites are identical except for the DocumentRoot and ServerName which are both correct.

At a bit of a loss as what to try now.

Comment: Please share your apache config file. If the certificate is valid this seems to be the only place an error might have occured with loading and presenting the certificate.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers. see [ask]

Comment: @Mowo as I say the config file is exactly the same as the subdomain that is working with the certificate except for DocumentRoot and ServerName which are both correct. ServerName is obviously just the domain with no subdomain element and DocumentRoot has the correct path.